# 301 Redirect with query string and anchor

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following URL:

`http://www.current-domain.com/register?tabs=2#tabs`

I need this to redirect to another URL on a new domain

`http://www.new-domain.com/register#register-form`

I have looked into 301 redirects and tried the following:

`Redirect 301 /register?tabs=2#tabs http://www.new-domain.com/register#register-form`

The problem is, when I hit the current URL, the new URL is:

`http://www.new-domain.com/register#register-form?tabs=4` which is incorrect

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is it ok to just match `http://www.current-domain.com/register?tabs=2` without anchors?

Comment: It needs the anchors as they match some javascript on the new redirect which anchors to some text

Comment: Anchors are not even passed to server so you cannot do this on server side directive like `mod_rewrite`. Better to handle it via Javascript only.

Comment: @anubhava what about just matching off the `tabs=2` query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?current-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tabs=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ http://www.new-domain.com/register#register-form [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the above does not work in IE or Safari?

Comment: I believe it should work across the browsers. Just make sure to clear browser cache on IE/Safari though I don't use those browsers.